# Generating xml within twig template

Tags: php, xml, symfony

I am trying to generate a sitemap, which works just fine if I do it in a standard xml file. The problem I am facing is that I need to generate a xml sitemap within twig file.

So i have this file: `sitemap.xml.twig` with this content:

```
{{ <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> }}

{{ <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"> }}
    {{ <url> }}
        {{ <loc>http://www.example.com/</loc> }}
        {{ <lastmod>2005-01-01</lastmod> }}
        {{ <changefreq>monthly</changefreq> }}
        {{ <priority>0.8</priority> }}
    {{ </url> }}
{{ </urlset> }}
```

But I get an error: `"message":"Unexpected token`

how can i make xml go into twig...?
sorry I am new to twig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{ literal }}` is the twig syntax for variable output, so you can't (and why should you?) use that to embrace your xml syntax. Simply write your xml as-is, and insert dynamic content by this twig syntax (and, of course, by `{% literal %}` for methods and language constructs.